# cannot display clickable link inside primefaces modal dialog

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to show a modal window with a link  point to my login page , the modal is shown correctly but the link is unclickable .

```
<p:dialog  header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100" >


                                <h:outputText value="session Expired   " />

                                <h:link value="Login page" outcome="login" />

            </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Try putting a link inside of `<h:form>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your link inside of a form:

```
<p:dialog  header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100" >

     <h:form>
       <h:outputText value="session Expired   " />

       <h:link value="Login page" outcome="login" />
     </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

References: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_link_tag.htm